# converting a column with 10 len string (numeric looking) and/or nan to numeric in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am not able to convert a column in my df. I have used

```
(dqa_proc_df.KI_2204995).apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

and

`dqa_proc_df['KI_2204995'] = pd.to_numeric(dqa_proc_df['KI_2204995'], errors='ignore')`

I get this error message: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'CHE-113.192.582MWST'

The contents of the column are as follows:

```
label: 0
content: 4890159554
label: 4
content: 4890159793
label: 5
content: 4180261069
label: 6
content: Nan
label: 7
content: 4940263587
label: 8
content: nan
label: 9
content: 4560276109
```

Comment: can you format the core in the proper way? Use four blank spaces before the code lines

Comment: Please also consider providing representation of both the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

What this error message is telling you is that one of value in your `KI_2204995` column is `CHE-113.192.582MWST`, and python cannot convert english into float number. You may need to define a way to take care of cases like this.

By the way, if your column contains only contains number and `.`, then you could have use `dqa_proc_df['KI_2204995'] = dqa_proc_df['KI_2204995'].astype(float)`

Comment: the same column also has CHE-113.192.582MWST, 13192582, 'DE251202658', as values. tried dqa_proc_df['KI_2204995'] = dqa_proc_df['KI_2204995'].map(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])), and the the ff: df['Name_'] = pd.to_numeric (df['Name_'], errors='ignore') or df['Name_'] = pd.to_numeric (df['Name_'], errors='coerse'). Result is 1.319258e+07 instead of 13192582 (as in 13 million not 1 point 3).

Comment: 'You may need to define a way to take care of cases like this' - what does this mean?

Comment: I would like to just convert the column to a numeric (or alphanumeric) field. In this way, if the test is: KI_2204995 > 1476185901 (true or false).